# Prestashop 1.7 Mail Alerts ps_emailalerts.php error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've encountered an interesting issue which is stopping Mail Alerts module from working on my Prestashop 1.7.5.1 shop.

I've just (25th April 2019) installed the module from the official repo (https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_emailalerts).

I activate it, go to Configuration, fill out "MERCHANT NOTIFICATIONS" section with my emails, click save, and I get this:

[image]

```
Warning on line 205 in file /var/www/html/shop.example.com/public_html/modules/ps_emailalerts/ps_emailalerts.php
[2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

repeated for every email I've typed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to some changes in PHP 7.3 and the fact that you have PHP warnings enabled (maybe you turned on the "DEV MODE" in PrestaShop?).

**You have three ways to fix this:**

1. Downgrade to PHP 7.1

   *or*
2. Edit the ps_emailalerts.php file on line 205 and add an `is_array() &&` before `count()` like this:

   `} elseif (!empty($email) && is_array($email) && count($email) > 0) {`

   *or*
3. Turn off PHP warnings and errors in php.ini and/or PrestaShop

I hope this helps.